# Scroll bar not part of div

Tags: html, css, angular

My css code is as:

```
.my-scrollable-component-style {
 overflow-y: auto;
 max-height: 368px;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

HTML is as:

```
<div class="my-scrollable-component-style">
    <child-component>
    </child-component>
</div>
```

Scroll is created, but it is not part of the div, instead it is displayed a bit away as in following image:

[image]

How can I integrate scroll in the dialog?angularan

Comment: I would check if `child-component` has right-padding on it or `.my-scrollable-component-style` is inheriting any right-margin.

Comment: Can you produce a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? I made [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/5f0p63z2/1/), but I don't see the problem.

Comment: put your background colour on the thing that has overflow, not on it's children